# Do all partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ of $f = u + iv$ have to be continuous for $f$ to be holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f = u + iv:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a complex function and suppose that the Cauchy-Riemann system of equations is satisfied at a point $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{C}$, that is the partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exist. This might be a nitpicky question, but none of my CA books address it: Isn't it then sufficient that either $u_x$ or $u_y$ is continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$ for $f$ to be analytic? The Cauchy-Riemann result is stated in all my written material essentially as: *If a function $f = u + iv$ has continuous partial derivatives and the CR system of equations is satisfied at a point $(x_0, y_0)$, then $f$ is holomorphic at $(x_0, y_0)$*.

However, there is also a result in multivariable calculus which states that the sufficient condition for a  multivariable function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ to be differentiable at $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is that i.) all partial derivatives of $F$ exist at $a$ ii.) at most one of the partial derivatives of $F$ does not exist in any neighbourhood of a excluding a or is not continuous in any neighbourhood containing $a$. Knowing this, doesn't it then follows that if we know a priori that, say, $u_x$ is continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$, then $u(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$. And since $u_x = v_y$ by the CR equations, it follows that also $v(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$?

Edit: The exact results I am referring to are:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: $u$ and $v$ will even by smooth (i.e. $\mathcal C^\infty $) on a neighborhood...

Comment: The conclusion is not true if you are considering just one point $(x_0,y_0).$ Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $ (x_0,y_0)=(0,0).$ Then $f$ has the complex derivative at $z=0,$ but $f$ is not analytic at $z=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Hmm, interesting! Could you take a look at the results which I included to my post? IMO, if $f = u + iv$ and all partial derivatives exist, the CR equations are satisfied and e.g. $u_x$ is continuous at some $(x_0, y_0)$, then $u$ and $v$ are differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$ and hence $f$ is analytic at $(x_0, y_0)$

Comment: I assume that analytic means that $f(z)$ is represented by a power series $\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n $ in a neighborhood of $z_0=x_0+iy_0.$ The function $fz)=|z|^2$ cannot be analytic as it is real valued. In Theorem 2.5.1 the assumptions are satisfied at all points in $U,$ not just one point $(x_0,y_0)\in U.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So to conclude this thread, do all partial derivatives need to be a priori continuous for a function to be analytic/holomorphic in addition to the CR equations, or does it suffice that the partial w.r.t. $x$ or $y$ or $u$ or $v$ is continuous?

Comment: No, apriori continuity of partial derivatves is not needed, just the differentiabilty. Exactly as in Theorem 2.5.1. On the other hand in order to show differentiabilty it suffices that the partial derivatives exist and are continuous. When you add CR equations it suffices that partial derivatives of $u$ or $v$ or wrt to $x$ or  $y$ are continuous.